# How to pass Parameter from controller (Content.ReadAsAsync) to api controller in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, parameter-passing

This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string Searchby, string SearchValue)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var productDetailUrl = Url.RouteUrl(
            "DefaultApi",
            new { httproute = "", controller = "Assets" },
            Request.Url.Scheme
        );
        var model = client
                    .GetAsync(productDetailUrl)
                    .Result
                    .Content.ReadAsAsync<AssetDetails[]>().Result;

        return View(model);}
```

searchby and searchvalue params are coming form

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#txtSearch').blur(function () {
        var Searchby = $('select[name="Searchby"]').val();
        var SearchValue = $("txtSearch").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Asset/Index',
            data: { Searchby: searchby, SearchValue: SearchValue },
        })
    });
});
```

how should i pass Searchby,SearchValue from ReadAsAsync

Comment: I added this in my webapiconfig  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Searchby}/{SearchValue}"
            );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just craft your uri as a string. It's unclear from your code what uri you want to request so I suggested how it might look. Also I transformed the code to use async pattern to avoid deadlocks.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string Searchby, string SearchValue)
{
    var productDetailUrl = string.Format("http://<hostname>/you/uri/here?searchBy={0}&searchValue={1}", SearchBy, SearchValue);

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(productDetailUrl);
    var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AssetDetails[]>();

    return View(model);
}
```